# Стиль биографического текста

Tags: стилистика

Скажите, пожалуйста, следующий текст принадлежит к научному и художественному стилям? Использованы эпитеты, метафоры, язык - не сухой теоретический, строго термилогический. Вообще зачастую "биография" принадлежит к обоим стилям? Однако преимущество остается за научным?

В ряду русских филологов второй половины XIX века особенно ярко выделяется имя Фёдора Ивановича Буслаева. Лингвист и литературовед, исследователь народной словесности и древнерусского искусства, он был блестящим педагогом и лектором, академиком, профессором Московского университета.

Ф. И. Буслаев продолжил отечественные традиции сравнительно-исторического изучения славянских языков, заложенные Александром Хри-стофоровичем Востоковым. Свои научные исследования Ф. И. Буслаев старался связывать с проблемами преподавания, а забота о школе прошла через всю его жизнь. После окончания Московского университета он в течение ряда лет работал учителем русского языка и литературы. Научный и педагогический опыт Ф. И. Буслаев обобщил в книге «О преподавании отечественного языка» (1844) — первой в нашем отечестве научной методике преподавания русского языка. Основная мысль этого фундаментального труда — о важности изучения родного языка в школе для развития личности, необходимости сравнительно-исторического изучения родного языка после усвоения его правил, значимости со-изучения языка и национальной культуры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, это не художественный стиль, это **научный, научно-популярный подстиль**. Именно в научно-популярном стиле широко используется общенаучная лексика и изобразительно-выразительные средства, свойственные публицистике и художественной литературе (оценочность и эмоциональность - *особенно ярко, блестящий педагог*). Информативность, стройность, логичность построения текста - черты этого стиля. Биография учёного, скорее всего, помещена в учебнике, справочнике, энциклопедии или в статье научного журнала.

Comment: Тут стилистически более правильно `из учебника, справочника...` Но дело в другом. Может, `размещена в учебнике...`? Или `помещена (во что?) в учебник`. Просто первый раз вижу такое согласование...

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили)

Comment: По Ожегову ПОМЕСТИТЬ, - ещённый (ён, ена); 1. что. Определить, найти место для чегон. П. книги на полку.
2. кого (что). Поселить. П. приезжего в отдельный номер.3. кого-что. Отдать кудан. для какойн. цели. П. ребёнка в детский сад.4. что. Напечатать, опубликовать. П. статью в журнале. П. объявление в газете.В последнем номере журнала поместили подборку стихов известного поэта. Разместить — 1. Расположить в определённом порядке. 2. Распределить между многими лицами .Примеры: Разместить посуду на полке, бельё в шкафу, выгодно разместить заказы. Статью не размещают, а помещают где? куда?

Comment: https://paronymonline.ru/%D0%A0/686

Comment: Ну вот открыл для себя что-то новое. Но даже гугл-поиск на запросы "помещен(а) в" и "поместить в" выдаёт результаты с согласованием "куда?", нежели "где?". Возможно, согласование "где?" уже мало распространено и, как следствие, устаревает.